# How to stop a cat from breaking glasses?

Tags: cats, behavior, training, feeding, psychology

When my cat drinks water from her water bowl she leaves in peace. But whenever I give her water from another bowl, she drinks then tries to break the glass. She pushes it with her nose and throws it off the surface it was on. If it was on the floor she'd still push it until she recognizes nothing is going to happen.

Why is she doing that? How do I stop her?

Comment: Is the alternative bowl a different shape from her regular one? Perhaps the one she tries to push down irritates her whiskers, so she tries to push it down to get to the water.

Comment: In any other glass even if it's the same kind and shape, if it's somewhere other than the place her food and water dishes are she'll try to break them after drinking. As if no one should drink after her but I know it's not the case, I just don't know why she does it. Sometimes it's obvious she does it for attention when we ignore her or don't come to the room she's in when she wants. But when I'm right there and giving her the bowl she drinks and after she's done drinking she'll try to push it. Of course at the time I'll hold it and not let it fall. But if I don't tell her ''No'' she does it..

Comment: ..and never minds my presence.

Comment: Still if I do tell her ''no''she stops which is of my benefit, but in my case I want her to stop it completely without me having to tell her no everytime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some cats just enjoy knocking things off counters. I think it is a play behavior. Use a stainless steel or plastic bowl to prevent broken bowls.

Answer (score 3):

A very simple way you could stop your cat from doing this, is rubbing a small amount of lemon juice around the bottom of the glass. Cats hate the citrusy smell, and won't put their nose against it. If this is the only water your cat is being given at this time, make sure not to overdo it on the lemon juice, and only put it near the bottom, otherwise your cat may not drink the water.

Comment: Wow I didn't know that, I'll try doing it, and don't worry she'll drink water weither it was from her bowl or any other bowl. Thanks